# How to use ImageSharp to convert a gif animation to a png spritesheet

Tags: c#, gif, sprite-sheet, imagesharp

I'm trying to create an animated GIF to PNG converter using SixLabors ImageSharp. I found this [documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/animatedgif.html) about creating a gif, but I want the reverse operation.

I can't find in the documentation how to copy a block of bytes to a destination image.

I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way to copy a block of bytes to an output image than using a byte per byte method.

Here's my attempt, but I'm have trouble with `WriteBytesToImage`

```cs
public static class GifToSpritesheet
{
    public static async Task<Image> Convert(Image gif)
    {
        var size = gif.Size();
        var nbFrames = gif.Frames.Count;

        var resultWidth = size.Width * nbFrames;
        var resultHeight = size.Height;

        var result = new Image<Rgba32>(resultWidth, resultHeight);
            
        int xOffset = 0;
            
        foreach (var frame in gif.Frames.Cast<ImageFrame<Rgba32>>())
        {
            var bytes = await GetBytesFromFrameAsync(frame);
            WriteBytesToImage(bytes, resultWidth, result);
        }

        return null;            
    }

    // Src : https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/gifs-in-console-output-imagesharp-and-spectreconsole
    private static async Task<byte[]> GetBytesFromFrameAsync(ImageFrame<Rgba32> imageFrame, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null)
    {
        using var image = new Image<Rgba32>(imageFrame.Width, imageFrame.Height);
        for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
            {
                image[x, y] = imageFrame[x, y];
            }
        }

        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
            await image.SaveAsBmpAsync(memoryStream, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        else
            await image.SaveAsBmpAsync(memoryStream);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    private static void WriteBytesToImage(byte[] bytes, int width, Image<Rgba32> result)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.Height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                // TODO : Do the code
                //result[j, i] = Rgba32(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've manage to flatten an animated gif to a single Image.

Here's the complete code :

```cs
public static class GifToSpritesheet
{
    public static async Task<Image> Convert(Image gif)
    {
        var size = gif.Size();
        var nbFrames = gif.Frames.Count;

        var resultWidth = size.Width * nbFrames;
        var resultHeight = size.Height;

        var result = new Image<Rgba32>(resultWidth, resultHeight);
            
        int xOffset = 0;
            
        foreach (var frame in gif.Frames.Cast<ImageFrame<Rgba32>>())
        {
            await Task.Run(() => WriteFrameToImage(frame, result, xOffset));
            xOffset += frame.Width;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void WriteFrameToImage(ImageFrame<Rgba32> imageFrame, Image<Rgba32> result, int xOffset = 0, int yOffset = 0)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, imageFrame.Height, (y, state) =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, imageFrame.Width, (x, stateCol) =>
            {
                result[x + xOffset, y + yOffset] = imageFrame[x, y];
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There's several problems with that code. 
- Don't use async if you don't need it. Use Task.CompletedTask outside the loop if required.
- The cast is not safe. Always decode using the generic API if pixel access is  required. 
- Use ProcessPixelRows for pixel access. Much more efficient

https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/pixelbuffers.html#efficient-pixel-manipulation

Comment: @JamesSouth I would love to see an example, as the documentation for common tasks like this is extremely sparse.

Comment: The docs are also open source. I wouldn't consider converting a gif to a spritesheet a common task.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code useful so I attempted to improve it.  Here are the changes per @JamesSouth suggestions. No warranty is implied.

```
private static void Extract(ImageFrame<Rgba32> sourceImage, Image<Rgba32> targetImage, int xOffset = 0)
{
    sourceImage.ProcessPixelRows(targetImage.Frames[0], (sourceAccessor, targetAccessor) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceImage.Height; i++)
        {
            Span<Rgba32> sourceRow = sourceAccessor.GetRowSpan(i);
            Span<Rgba32> targetRow = targetAccessor.GetRowSpan(i).Slice(xOffset);
            sourceRow.CopyTo(targetRow);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]